# How to retrieve bytes data from request body in Azure Function App

Tags: c#, python, byte, azure-functions, azureportal

In Python, I converted an image into bytes. Then, I pass the bytes to an Azure HTTP Trigger function app endpoint URL (Azure Portal) like this, just like usual when calling Azure cognitive services.

```py
image_path = r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\bicycle.jpg"
image_data = open(image_path, "rb").read()
print(len(image_data)) # print length to compare later
url = "https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/HTTPTrigger1........."
headers    = {'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers,
                             data=image_data)
```

However, I have no idea on how to retrieve the bytes data in the function app on Azure Portal. I tried the following (C#) but it did not work. It seems like `ReadToEndAsync()` is not meant to read bytes data from request body? Or is it because of `HttpRequest`?

```cs
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    byte[] imageBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestBody); 
    log.LogInformation(imageBytes.Length.ToString());
    // the length logged is totally not the same with len(image_data) in Python

    //ignore the following lines (not related)
    return name != null
    ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult("OK")
    : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
}
```

Any idea about this? I do know a workaround using base64 string but I'm just really curious about how Azure cognitive services do it!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do not use `ReadToEndAsync()`, instead, use `MemoryStream()`. `ReadToEndAsync()` is used to read string buffer which can mess up the incoming bytes data. Use `CopyToAsync()` and then convert the memory stream into bytes array to preserve the incoming bytes data.

```cs
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    //string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); 
    await req.Body.CopyToAsync(ms);
    byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
    log.LogInformation(imageBytes.Length.ToString());


    // ignore below (not related)
    string finalString = "Upload succeeded";
    Returner returnerObj = new Returner();
    returnerObj.returnString = finalString;
    var jsonToReturn = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(returnerObj);

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) {
        Content = new StringContent(jsonToReturn, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
    };
}

public class Returner
{
    public string returnString { get; set; }
}
```

Reference/Inspired by:
https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/sep/14/accepting-raw-request-body-content-in-aspnet-core-api-controllers