# How to get image data from request body in Azure Functions v2 and convert to Stream

Tags: c#, .net, function, azure, azure-functions

I need to read image send to Azure Function v2 as Stream and then pass that Stream to method to work with image.

I tried several approaches ie. [from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54944607/how-to-retrieve-bytes-data-from-request-body-in-azure-function-app) or [this blog post](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/sep/14/accepting-raw-request-body-content-in-aspnet-core-api-controllers) and none of them worked - every time the Stream that is passed to the method have non valid data. also if I read request Body as string it shows some crap. Final solution that I think is the most logical is posted below:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
      [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)]
      HttpRequest req,
      ILogger log)
{
      Product product;
      using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
      {                
         await req.Body.CopyToAsync(ms);
         ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

         //Then I need to pass Stream to another method that calls Azure Custom Vision endpoint
         product = await _identifyService.IdentifyProduct(ms);
      }
}
```

Also I tried several other approaches ie.:

```cs
      MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
      await req.Body.CopyToAsync(ms);
      byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
      log.LogInformation(imageBytes.Length.ToString());

      var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
      memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
      // Then pass memoryStream to the method.
```

or reading req.Body as string with StreamReader. None of this approaches worked.

The request from React app done with ajax looks more or less like that (shortened it to be more readable):

```
file: File = .... //File from form

const reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
var binary = reader.result;

fetch(`${API_URL}/IdentifyProduct`, {
      method: 'post',
      body: binary
    }).then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    })
```

Maybe somebody had similar problem and have solution, because I don't have any other idea how to get it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I came up with a solution. I was sending request in a wrong way. It turns out that file can be send in a body without any prepparations. So now JS looks like this:

```
file: File = .... //File from form

fetch(`${API_URL}/IdentifyProduct`, {
      method: 'post',
      body: file
    }).then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    })
```

And then reading it in Azure Function in C#:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
      [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)]
      HttpRequest req,
      ILogger log)
{
      Product product = await _identifyService.IdentifyProduct(req.Body);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**1. If your image data is in the form, you can use this:**

```
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    req.Form.Files[0].CopyTo(ms);
    ms.Position = 0;
```

This will get the first image in your post request.

**2. If your image data is put into a binary request,**

Just use `req.Body` is ok.The `req.Body` is stream.

Comment: Nope, any of those solutions work. But I come up with an idea that actually worked. Checkout my answer :)